# How can I compare environments in R?

Tags: r, comparison

I have 2 environments I would like to compare. What is the best way to do that? Should I use some sort of binary comparison to check if they are identical? I currently tried the following options, but I am not sure if its the proper way:

```
env1 = load("environment1")
env2 = load("environment2")

all.equal(env1, env2)

identical(env1, env2)
```

both return true, I tried `isTRUE(all.equal.environment(env1,env2))` , this returns FALSE since its says its characters I'am comparing..

I am pretty new in R , so all tips are welcom!

Comment: what is inside `env1` and `env2`?

Comment: it has 2 cdf files , these two librarys are used `library(hgu133plus2cdf)`
`library(hthgu133pluspmcdf)`

Comment: I asked you because you will provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/01/how-to-compare-objects-in-r/
install and load the package "waldo", and then run compare

```
file1 <- "environment2"
file2 <- "environment2"
file1.data <- load (file1, file1.env <- new.env ())
file2.data <- load (file2, file2.env <- new.env ())
compare (file1.env, file2.env)
```